# Google maps snapshot getting removed from Canvas

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to create a screenshot of my Activity with a Google map in it. My code stopped working after updating my Google API's from 7.xx to 8.1.0`, but i can't find any relevant changes in their changelogs.

This is what happens: I take a screenshot of my activity with view.getDrawingCache. I then draw the snapshot of the map on the correct position on my canvas. This all works fine. When  i want to draw my "backBitmap" over my snapshot, it removed the snapshot from the Canvas again.

How come my maps snapshot is removed from the canvas as soon as i call this line?:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Entire function:

```
GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
    try {
      view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      Bitmap backBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
      Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight() - DpConverter.dpToPx(50), backBitmap.getConfig());
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
      canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, 0, mapView.getTop() + getStatusBarHeight(view), null);
      canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/AppScreenshots/" + name);

      bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
      view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: you should swap the drawings; the back as first and snapshot as second

Comment: That works but i have some elements displayed on top of the map, which are then gone in the screenshot.

Comment: then you should try to replace pixels inside the map area with transparent pixels. Because when you take a screenshot of the app, the map area becomes black and if drawn over the map, this will be hidden. That's not easy, because replace black with transparent is not working at 100%, if some of your overlays contains black pixels they will be transparent too...